# Two-group "ANCOVA" with Theil-Sen?

Tags: regression, inference, ancova, robust, two-sample

("ANCOVA" might typically refer to using at least three groups. In what I do, I am always comparing two groups, and that is what I mean throughout this question.)

I know how to do ANCOVA via OLS regression and inference on the group parameter. If I want to do something similar but for a comparison of medians instead of means, I know how to do it with MAE quantile regression and inference on the group parameter.

If I want to do it using something like Theil-Sen estimation, is there an extension of Theil-Sen? The idea I have is to do Theil-Sen on just the control group points and then Theil-Sen on just the treatment group points and compare the intercepts (maybe with bootstrap if I'm willing to wait around a while). After all, in OLS or MAE, I'm comparing the intercepts of two parallel lines to examine if one is consistently above the other.

Yet this feels sketchy.

Thoughts?